# Scrolling Bootstrap Modal when cursor is over a “position: fixed” element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two fixed buttons that appears with a bootstrap modal so when the user scrolls down the modal the buttons remain in the vertical center of the screen… But when the cursor is over one of this buttons the modal won’t scroll. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: You can start by posting some relevant HTML and CSS of the problem.

Comment: On stackoverflow, you must post your code and show us your implementation